# Can a PHP Generator Recover From an Uncaught Exception?

Tags: php, generator

Consider this simple generator function in PHP.

```
function createAGenerator() {
    echo 'Before First Yield',"\n";
    yield 'First Yield';
    echo 'Before Second Yield',"\n";
    yield 'Second Yield';
    echo 'Before Third Yield',"\n";
    yield 'Third Yield';
}
```

If I throw into this generator using the generator object's `throw` method

```
$generator = createAGenerator();
try {
    $generator->throw(new Exception('Throwing into a Generator'));
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught Exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
echo 'Resuming Main Program Execution',"\n";
```

the generator function will re-throw the exception for me to catch.  This all works as I expect.

However -- my generator now seems permanently stuck.  If I try to move on to the `next` yield, or `send` a new value in, the generator appears to just return `NULL`.  For example, the following program

```
<?php
function createAGenerator() {
    echo 'Before First Yield',"\n";
    yield 'First Yield';
    echo 'Before Second Yield',"\n";
    yield 'Second Yield';
    echo 'Before Third Yield',"\n";
    yield 'Third Yield';
}

$generator = createAGenerator();
try {
    $generator->throw(new Exception('Throwing into a Generator'));
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught Exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
echo 'Resuming Main Program Execution',"\n";

var_dump($generator->send('Some Value'));
var_dump($generator->current());
var_dump($generator->next());
var_dump($generator->current());
```

Returns the following output.

```
Before First Yield
Caught Exception: Throwing into a Generator
Resuming Main Program Execution
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Is there a way for a generator to recover from this?  Or does an uncaught exception in a generator "break" this current instance of the generator?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this - signalling the generator or just seeing why it breaks?

Comment: @NigelRen Thank you for responding.  I don't have any particular goal in mind with this question.  Instead I'm trying to better understand generator code execution for all possible cases.

Comment: Just that you use `->send()`, but don't pick up the value, using `$ret = yield 'First Yield';` will allow you to 'signal' the generator for some specific case.

Answer (score 1):

When you throw an exception, the generator will skip right to the end of the function. This is exactly what happens in a regular functions, if that function called something that threw an exception.

Your two options are:

1. To catch it in the generator (or use finally).
2. To not throw it at all

The idea of throwing an exception and use it as a "temporary" messaging system but resume normal operation is a bit weird. It sounds like a bit of an abuse of exceptions. Perhaps what you are trying to achieve can be accomplished without throwing an exception.

If you're trying to model an operation that has multiple steps and each can individually fail or succeed, one option might be to just yield the exception and not throw it.

Comment: Thank you for the response!  In the interest of full disclosure, I'm not trying to achieve any particular goal here, I'm just trying to understand code execution into and out of a generator for all the cases provided by the generator's methods, including the weird-to-me throw :)

Comment: @AlanStorm if you have experience with modern javascript, it might help to pretend yield is 'await'.